# Accessing global attributes from inside a macro in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I've been using macros in Jinja2 extensively and find them very DRY-ish; but there is one thing bothering me: how to access global stuff from macros? It would be really neat if I could somehow access url_for() natively from a macro.

Comment: What platform is this for? Flask, Django, a custom framework that uses Jinja2, or something entirely different?

Comment: Jinja2 is being used in combination with webapp2 on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make any callable available in the Jinja environment:

```
jinja_env = Environment(...)
jinja_env.globals['url_for'] = url_for
```

For example, this output u'foobar' in a shell:

```
from jinja2 import Environment
env = Environment()
env.globals['foo'] = lambda: "foobar"
env.from_string('{% macro bar() %}{{ foo() }}{% endmacro %}{{ bar() }}').render()
```

Comment: Yes, I've taken care of the environment, and url_for() is accessible from a Jinja2 template, but not from within a macro.

Comment: Added working code in my answer to show how I tested  it. Did I misunderstand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I found out that my url_for is actually a context element, and of course the context is not available from within a macro. Need to actually put url_for in the environment's globals. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to get at the `request`, which is available outside a macro but not inside. Any idea how I can get at this?

Comment: If you are doing "import" of the macro from a file, then this question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118860/jinja2-macro-import-with-context-and-global-variables-from-file-html-impor