# How to exclude an host in Ansible Jinja2 template for-loop?

Tags: for-loop, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have a template named `foo.yml.j2` used in an Ansible task to generate a `foo.yml` file:

```yaml
      {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
      {{ host }},
      {% endfor %}
```

Everything works fine except I need something like the following statement: For every host in `ansible_play_hosts_all` except for `host==bar` do this or that.

Is this achievable or the only way to do this is to categorize my hosts in different groups and use `ansible_play_hosts_group`?

Comment: Both answers are great and work like charm, I accepted the longer one since it gives more options and is more well-explained.

Comment: There is also a `for … if …` construct in Jinja if you don’t have enough option already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655155/jinja2-for-loop-with-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more options. The trivial one is using the condition in Jinja

```yaml
{% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
{% if host != 'bar' %}
{{ host }},
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Fit the format to your needs.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: host_1,host_2,host_3
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
          {% if host != 'host_2' %}
          {{ host }},
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    host_1,
    host_3,
```

---

The next option is to remove blacklisted hosts from the loop, e.g.

```yaml
blacklist: [host_2]
```

The template below gives the same result

```yaml
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all|difference(blacklist) %}
          {{ host }},
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, you've helped me before, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reject` filter to take your host out of the list so that it is not part of your loop:

```yaml
{% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all | reject('==', 'bar') %}
{{ host }},
{% endfor %}
```