# Jinja2 macro import "with context" and global variables: {% from file.html import macro_name with context %}

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

In Jinja2 template engine for python, my macro "with context" could not access the global variables from the context.

Import statements:

```
{% import 'en-US/my_macro.html' as  all_macros %}
{% from 'en-US/my_macro.html' import  the_macro  with context  %}
```

Macro usage:

```
{{ all_macros.the_macro() }}
```

The macro is being called, but the globals have no value.

Here's the relevant docs for ["with context"](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#import-context-behavior)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue arises because there are 2 ways to call the macro.
One is from the all_macros  import.
The second is with the name  the_macro.

If I use the call:

```
{{ the_macro() }}
```

Then the macros have access to the global variables from the context!
This is really a clarification of the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#import-context-behavior).